# SQL XML column query for both attributes and elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

This is my first experience of querying from an XML column in SQL Server and I am close to achieving my desired outcome.

However I would like assistance as there are elements and attributes I would like - I am successful in getting the attributes, however the elements are being merged into a single row instead of splitting them out in different rows.

An example of an XML record in the DB:

```
<Attributes>
    <Map>
        <entry key="name" value="John Doe" />
        <entry key="department" value="Finance" />
        <entry key="employeeNumber" value="123456" />
        <entry key="phone">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>TBA</String>
                </List>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="OrgStructure">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>top</String>
                    <String>person</String>
                    <String>organizationalPerson</String>
                    <String>user</String>
                </List>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="Membership">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>Group1</String>
                    <String>Group2</String>
                    <String>Group3</String>
                </List>
            </value>        
        </entry>
    </Map>
</Attributes>
```

**SQL Query:**

```
    SELECT  

    m.c.value('@key', 'varchar(max)') as xmlkey,
    m.c.value('@value', 'varchar(max)') as xmlvalue,
    m.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as xmlString

    from #TEMPDB as s 

    cross apply s.attributes.nodes('Attributes/Map/entry') as m(c)
```

**Result:**

```
xmlkey            xmlvalue      xmlString

name              John Doe
department        Finance
employeeNumber    123456
phone             NULL          TBA
OrgStructure      NULL          toppersonorganizationalPersonuser
Membership        NULL          Group1Group2Group3
```

**Desired Result:**

```
xmlkey            xmlvalue      xmlString

name              John Doe
department        Finance
employeeNumber    123456
phone             NULL          TBA
OrgStructure      NULL          top
OrgStructure      NULL          person
OrgStructure      NULL          organizationalPerson
OrgStructure      NULL          user
Membership        NULL          Group1
Membership        NULL          Group2
Membership        NULL          Group3
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

Comment: This is a very good question: Sample, own effort, clear explanation. +1 from my side!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT  
m.c.value('@key', 'varchar(max)') as xmlkey,
m.c.value('@value', 'varchar(max)') as xmlvalue,
n.s.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ListValue
from #TEMPAK2 as s 
cross apply s.attributes.nodes('Attributes/Map/entry') as m(c)
outer apply m.c.nodes('value/List/String') AS n(s);
```

I assume, that you have two types of `<entry>`

- name-value pairs
- such with a `<value>` element

It looks like a `<value>` element has a *`<List>` of `<String>`* Structur. At least in all cases you show us.

Comment: Hi Aadil, thx for the edits :-D I tested against a typed variable and copy-pasted this wrong...

Comment: I made slight amendments, but this worked perfectly. Thank you!